# iScroll Not scrolling content, just bounces back to top

Tags: iscroll

I have read a bunch of forums on this but none have solved my  problem. I'm sure its something small I'm missing

Here is iscroll initialization:

```
// make PI scroll
piScroll2 = new iScroll('pi_scroll2');
```

Here is my css:

```
.pi_panel.large .content{
position: absolute;
width: 963px;
height: 616px;
top: 65px;
left:30px;
background:none;
/*background:url(../images/ISI_body.png) repeat-y;*/
overflow:scroll;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
```

}

```
#FullPiWrapper
{
   position:relative; 
   z-index: 1; 
   overflow:hidden; 
   top: 60px; 
   width:980px;
   height: 610px;
}

.pi_panel .pi_box{
padding: 0px;
margin: 20px 0px;
```

}

Here is my html:

```
<!-- BEGIN:   PI PANEL LARGE -->
    <div class="pi_panel large">
     <div class="topBarPiFull">
                <div class="title">Full Prescribing Information</div>
                <div class="close_button_fullpi">Close</div>
                <div class="annotated_pi_button">Annotated PI</div>
            </div>
<!--            <div class="popContent"></div>-->
          <div class="content" id="FullPiWrapper">

                <div id="pi_scroll2">


                    <div class="pi_box" >
                        <img src="_globals/images/PI/pi_1.png"/>
                        <img src="_globals/images/PI/pagebreak.png" />
                        <img src="_globals/images/PI/pi_2.png"/>
                        <img src="_globals/images/PI/pagebreak.png" />
                        <img src="_globals/images/PI/pi_3.png"/>
                        <img src="_globals/images/PI/pagebreak.png"/>
                        <img src="_globals/images/PI/pi_4.png"/>
                        <img src="_globals/images/PI/pagebreak.png"/>
                        <img src="_globals/images/PI/pi_5.png"/>
                        <img src="_globals/images/PI/pagebreak.png" />
                        <img src="_globals/images/PI/pi_6.png"/>
                        <img src="_globals/images/PI/pagebreak.png" />
                        <img src="_globals/images/PI/pi_7.png"/>
                        <img src="_globals/images/PI/pagebreak.png" />
                        <img src="_globals/images/PI/pi_8.png"/>
                        <img src="_globals/images/PI/pagebreak.png" />
                        <img src="_globals/images/PI/pi_9.png"/>
                        <img src="_globals/images/PI/pagebreak.png" />
                        <img src="_globals/images/PI/pi_10.png"/>
                    </div>
                 </div>

            </div>
     </div>
    <!-- END:   PI PANEL LARGE -->
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Issue was, you cannot have ANY parent's div class display set to 'none' when the page first loads. So I set 'pi_panel large' to display: 'block';

Comment: Plus 1 from me. To add to your answer, iscroll's container element must be visible before iscroll is initialised. I just battled with iscroll on an ipad webapp, where all views are displayed dynamically.

Comment: ** Also see the answer here for issues with iscroll 5:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962095/iscroll-5-not-working-when-2nd-page-should-be-scrollable

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that the container's height exceeds the wrapper's height i.e. don't make `height:100%`. For example, if the wrapper contains a container, and there are 10 divs in the container:

If Each of the divs is 100px the wrapper might be 150px. Then Container has to be 1000px (not 100% !)

Answer (score 4):

give a height to your wrapper, it just worked for me.

```
.wrapper1 {
    position:absolute; z-index:1;
    top:250px; bottom:0px; left:3%;
    margin-left:25px;
    width:100%;
    background:none;
    overflow:auto;
    height:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get around the "div display none" issue, do the following after loading the data in your grid, div, etc:

```
            myScroll.refresh();
            myScroll.scrollTo(0, 0, 1000);
```

Where myScroll has been loaded:

> var myScroll = new iScroll('friendsWrapperDrug', { desktopCompatibility: true, vScroll: true, hScroll: false, hScrollbar: false, lockDirection: true });

Answer (score 0):

```
myScroll.refresh();
myScroll.scrollTo(0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score -1):

This problem occurs when you have a `container` div for your `wrapper` The fix for this is to set the height of the `container` to `99%`.

Following is the CSS which finally fixed this issue for me:

```
#productsScreen{ /* my container */
    height: 99%;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
#productListWrapper{
    background:transparent;
    position:absolute; 
    z-index:1;
    top: 88px;
    bottom:49px; 
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
}
#productsListScroller {
    position:absolute; z-index:1;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score -2):

Another solution that works for me is wrapping iScroll init function with setTimeout. This will give some time for the browser to render the element before iScroll is applied.

Comment: this is a terrible idea. Do it on DOM ready or when you show the scroller (if you are changing visibility dynamically)